# JAVA program to connect to IBM PCOMM

Tags: java, autohotkey

Please can you assist me on how to connect JAVA to IBM PCOMM and interact with its screen. Right now, I am just running IBM PCOMM using AutoHotKey (Run and SendInput), no API at all, just an automated keyboard input care of AHK script.
I am also thinking of writing AHK script to connect to IBM PCOMM and run it in my JAVA program as exe, but unfortunately, I don't know either how to write that script.

I am using Eclipse JUNO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also doing the same things like your. I'm using jacob - a com-java bridge component for java. I've just started my project for one week and the result I've got is quite fessible. Until know, I can wrap all the PCOMM com object by java and work with it properly. You can study jacob at this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/ and danadler.com/jacob/ .

Comment: thanks Dung Pham for the suggestion, I have now managed to connect to PCOMM using Autohotkey's ControlSend and send commands thru PCOMM's object. I will also try to study JACOB as it seems more feasible